# How can you keep the positions of an array the same while sorting?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, frequency

I am writing a Caesar cipher decoding program that sorts the frequency of letters of a message in descending order. My issue is when I print out the results the positions of the frequencies in the array no longer match the letters I have set up. How do I fix this? I have other code that removes punctuation and capitals, all characters besides spaces and lowercase letters from the message being decoded.

I have trimmed down the code to just what is being questioned.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void sortArray(int*, int);

int main()
{    

    string fileContent = "a coded message which is several hundreds of characters long is being passed into the program";

    int count[26];

// This code is skipping over spaces and other characters

    for(int f = 0; f < fileContent.length(); f++)
    {
            if(fileContent[f] == 32)
            {
                    continue;
            }

            if(fileContent[f] >= 48 && fileContent[f] <= 57)
            {
                    continue;
            }

            count[(fileContent[f]-'a')%26]++;
     }

// Here is where my issue begins. In sortArray, the position of the characters are being changed.

     cout << "Letter frequency: Most common to least common" << endl;

     sortArray(count, 26);

     for(int p = 0; p < 26; p++)
     {
           cout << char(p + 97) << ": " << count[p]  << endl;
     }

    return 0;
}



void sortArray(int* srcArray, int numElements)
{
        for(int x = 0; x < numElements; x++)
        {
            int max = srcArray[x];
            int maxIndex = x;
            int hold;

            for(int y = x + 1; y < numElements; y++)
            {
                    if(srcArray[y] > max)
                    {
                            max = srcArray[y];
                            maxIndex = y;
                    }
            }

            hold = srcArray[x];
            srcArray[x] = max;
            srcArray[maxIndex] = hold;
            hold = 0;

        }
}
```

Please kindly let me know how I can solve this issue, I've been theorizing but I cannot seem to figure out a viable solution.

Comment: can u please post an output u are getting and what is expected?

Comment: Consider creating a structure containing a character and integer for frequency or just std::pair<char, int>, create an array of that and sort accordingly

Comment: @Valgrind1691 Yes. So in the line" count[(fileContent[f]-'a')%26]++; " i am saving each character as a position in the array int count[26].then i am passing this array into sortArray.Does this answer your question? please let me know if you'd like me to edit this provided code to include more of the program or what is returns after running.

Comment: @hammonak updated my answer,check,it will solve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

After you compute the frequency in count array.

```
std::array<std::pair<char, int>, 26> pairArray;
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
{
    pairArray[i] = std::make_pair('a' + i, count[i]);
}

std::sort(pairArray.begin(), pairArray.end(), myCompare);

for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    std::cout << pairArray[i].first << ": " << pairArray[i].second << std::endl;
```

For `myCompare`,

```
bool myCompare(const std::pair<char, int>& p1, const std::pair<char, int>& p2)
{
    return p1.second > p2.second;
}
```

This should sort the array in descending order.

Comment: Using this I wouldn't need the sortArray function at all, would I? Also, does pairArray meant to replace count[]?

Comment: You can still choose to use sortArray but you need to modify it to sort based on second value which is the frequency. The code above is meant after you finish computing frequency in your `count[]`, but you can also choose to start off with pairArray right away and count frequency using it.

Comment: Also take note to initialize your count[] with 0 by doing `int count[26] = {0};`. C++ does not initialize value for you when you declare a variable or array.

Comment: Sorry for the questions but I am just a beginner in c++. I am confused because I do not know how to initialize the myCompare function. What does it get inside of the parens? For example, "void sortArray(int*, int);" for my compare it would be what? bool myCompare(_____,______);

Comment: `bool myCompare(const std::pair<char, int>&, const std::pair<char, int>&);`
For a lazy man like me, I just put the entire function before int main()

Comment: I don't understand how myCompare, sort, array, and pairArray are being utilized or initialized. You say that I COULD use sortArray but i'd have to modify it. Why would this code be added if it's not the modification, and it doesn't do what sortArray does? I'm very confused

Comment: Your sortArray function is designed to work for an integer array but now we are sorting an pair array instead and we are sorting it based on its second value so you would need to modify your sortArray if you want to sort pairArray. What I did is I just use std::sort to do the sorting, myCompare is just a function writen to tell std::sort how to compare items inside my pairArray.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because you have frequencies in the array but the frequencies are not mapped to corresponding character. When the frequencies are sorted,the array is rearranged but your printing of the frequencies is not character dependent,you are printing characters from a-z and assigning frequencies as they are in sorted array.

What you can do is map the frequencies with corresponding character. One solution can be using an unordered map,char being key. An unordered map because it won't internally sort the map on character value,so u can maintain frequency ordering as well.

You can also use vector with pair as @lamandy suggested.

```
vector< pair <char, int> > vect;
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    vect.push_back(make_pair(char(i + 97), count[i]));
}

sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), sortbysecVal);

// Printing the sorted vector(after using sort())
cout << "The vector after sort operation is:\n";
for (int i = 0; i<26; i++)
{
    // "first" and "second" are used to access
    // 1st and 2nd element of pair respectively
    cout << vect[i].first << " "
        << vect[i].second << endl;
}
```

sort by second value of pair

```
bool sortbysecVal(const pair<int, int> &a,  const pair<int, int> &b)
  return (a.second > b.second);
```

Once after you have calculated frequencies,you can use this,this will solve your purpose and you wont need your sort function.

P.S : One more thing,you must initialize your (array)count to 0,like int count[26] = {0},because initially it contains garbage if uninitialized and adding up 1 ( count[(fileContent[f]-'a')%26]++;) to a garbage will not produce result(frequency) u expect

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably a three-liner for a standard library guru, which I am not quite yet. I hate the standard library. It makes programming so easy that anyone can do it.

Here are two versions that I hacked out. This is fun.

```
#include <map>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using counted = std::pair<char, unsigned>;

std::vector<counted> 
counted_chars(const std::string_view input) {
  // Return a vector of <char, count> pairs, where char is an uppercase
    // letter, and count is the number of occurrences of the letter (upper or lower).
    // It is sorted from highest count to lowest.
    using namespace std;
    map<char, unsigned> count;
    // Count them.
    for(char next: input) {if (isalpha(next)) {count[toupper(next)] += 1;}}

    // Sort them
    vector<counted> sorted(count.size());
    copy(count.cbegin(), count.cend(), sorted.begin());
    sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), [](counted c1, counted c2) 
      { return c1.second > c2.second; });

    return sorted;
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "a coDed; MESSage which_is several hundreds of characters long is being passed into the program";
    auto result = counted_chars(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Another one that doesn't use std::map.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using counted = std::pair<char, unsigned>;

std::vector<counted> counted_chars(std::string input) {

    using namespace std;
    input.resize(remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](char ch) { return !isalpha(ch); })-input.begin());
    for(char &ch: input) { ch = toupper(ch); }
    sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    string present {input};
    present.resize(unique(present.begin(), present.end())-present.begin());
    std::vector<counted> sorted;
    for (char ch:present) {sorted.push_back(make_pair(ch, count(input.begin(), input.end(), ch)));}
    sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), [](counted c1, counted c2) { return c1.second > c2.second; });
    return sorted;
}

int main() {
    std::string str = " -- I have always wished for my computer to be as easy to use as my telephone; My wish has come true because I can no longer figure out how to use my telephone.";
    auto result = counted_chars(std::move(str));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can cut down on the sorting by copying the values into a `map<unsigned, char>` swapping the order of the pair. If you can use Boost, a [bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) is exactly correct for this situation.

Comment: @Caleth - I don't understand the part about copying the values into a map and swapping the order of the pairs.

Comment: `for (auto & pair : count) { reversed[pair.second] = pair.first; }`

Comment: @Caleth - The map "count" is not reversible. There can be multiple letters with the same count.